# Google maps draw route with updating movement

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Just finished my application that shows a route between two given positions with a MapView. Nothing fancy, I've just started with google maps. After some thoughts I came across that it would be nice if it was redrawn on movement like a real GPS-service.

So my questions are:

- How hard is it to implement a GPS on your own? I understand that I can make one now by continuously fecthing a kml file every once in a while. But how efficient is this really considering batteryusage and CPU? Google maps lets you request 2500times/day, does each of these updates counts as one?
- Can you start the Google maps application with given start and end position? This might be a simpler solution for me then..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whay don't you open google maps with intent giving your starting point and end point.

```
Intent navigation = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
        .parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="
                + Constants.latitude + ","
                + Constants.longitude + "&daddr="
                + latitude + "," + longitude));
startActivity(navigation);
```

This opens any maps application. Means a browser or google maps application. If you just want google maps and get rid of the dialog you can give the intent a hint as to which package you want to use.

Before the `startActivity()` add this:

```
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
```

Comment: I thinks also will be pleased to add to url "http://maps.google.com/maps?...." + ""&sensor=false&mode=driving""